# Не получается передать массив строк из одного класса в другой

Tags: android, массивы, arraylist

Есть массив строк в классе Unit. Мне необходимо передать его в класс Add_Ing. Перечитал не один десяток статей, но всё, что у меня получилось, это обратиться к определённому индексу массива из второго класса и достать соответствующее значение. Можно ли как-то создать массив в классе Add_Ing и записать в него все данные из массива класса Unit.

Класс Unit ( содержит исходный массив )

```
public class Unit extends AppCompatActivity {

public static ArrayList<String> units = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_unit);
    setTitle("Единицы измерения");

    units.add("л");
    units.add("мл");
    units.add("гр");
    units.add("кг");
    units.add("ч.л.");
    units.add("ст.л.");
    units.add("шт.");
    units.add("зуб.");
    }
}
```

Класс Add_Ing

```
public class Add_ingred extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText et_unit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_ingred);
    et_unit = findViewById(R.id.et_unit);
    // Обращение к определённому индексу массива из класса Unit
    String a;
    a = Unit_ing.units.get(0);

    et_unit.setText(a);
}
```

Comment: Можно. Точно также как вы завели переменную `String a` и в нее поместили первое значение из units - вы можете создать переменную массива (локальную, или поле класса/объекта) и добавить в нее весь ваш массив, но вот только зачем? Есть же уже массив со всеми единицами измерения в классе Unit и почему бы его везде где надо не использовать?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Я собственно этого и пытаюсь добиться, только, видимо слишком сложными путями. Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее, как можно использовать данный у меня массив где и как захочу. Быть может, есть определённая документация на этот повод ?

Comment: Использование публичной статической переменной класса

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вам предложил воспользоваться отдельным классом используя паттерн [синглтона](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/singleton.php). Таким образом на период работы с приложением вы всегда сможете использовать массив в разных частях программы. Для начала создадим синглтон:

```
public class Singleton { 
    private static Singleton instance; 

    private Singleton (){ 
    } 

    public static Singleton getInstance(){ 
        if (null == instance){ 
           instance = new Singleton(); 
        } 
        return instance; 
    } 
}
```

теперь добавим в него переменную вашего массива:

```
 ArrayList<String> units = new ArrayList<>();
```

будет как-то так:

```
public class Singleton { 
        private static Singleton instance; 
        ArrayList<String> units = new ArrayList<>();

        private Singleton (){ 
        } 

        public static Singleton getInstance(){ 
            if (null == instance){ 
               instance = new Singleton(); 
            } 
            return instance; 
        } 
    }
```

дальше при работе с массивом из класса-активности `Unit` мы сетим данные в массив из синглтона:

```
Singleton().getInstance().units = units;
```

и дальше в другой активности мы можем взять данные из него:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_ingred);
    ...



     ArrayList<String> sinUnits = Singleton().getInstance().units;

    ...
     }
```

Так же есть и второй вариант - использовать SharedPreferences. Сохраняя данные в настройки приложение вы сможете их использовать даже после того как убьете и заново запустите активность:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
prefs.putStringSet("key", set).commit();
```

получить данные можно таким способом:

```
Set<String> set = myScores.getStringSet("key", null);
```

Ну и наконец - можно использовать базу данных. Но судя по кол-ву данных поднимать ее не имеет смысла. Лучше использовать любой из вариантов представленных выше.